# How to change the specific button text colour programmatically in the UIAlertController

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

I want to changes the colour of the "Cancel" button in UIAlertController to Orange and keep the colour of "Log Out" button as it is. I have attached the screenshot and the code of the alert controller below.

[image]

Code for the alert view

```
alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Are you sure you want to log out?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Log out", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in

        println("Log Out button clicked.")

        prefs.setBool(false, forKey: "Isloggedin")
        NSUserDefaults.resetStandardUserDefaults()
        prefs.setBool(true, forKey: "IsEmail")
        prefs.setObject(email, forKey: "loggedemail")
        prefs.synchronize()
        let mainview = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mainscreen") as! mainViewController

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mainview, animated: true)
    }))

    //alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
        println("Cancel button clicked.")
    }))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: {
        println("completion block.")


    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a custom alert in which we can make changes as per our requirement.

I have attached the GitHub [Link](https://github.com/Kadasiddha/iOSAlert)